# signalr async response javascript callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr.client

Please can you advise on best way to pass my response from a signalR hub to a function call which had a call back .. I've tried a global variable to store the call back and call that on receive data but no luck. here's what i like to do;

```
school.lib.setmytime = function(_time){

 console.log('mytime is :' + _time);
}

school.lib.gettime = data.getservertime(school.lib.setmytime);
```

---

```
var myhub;

data.connection = function(){
    $connection.hub.url = 'http://myserver.com:65442';
    $connection.hub.start();

    myhub = $.connection.adminHub;

    myhub.client.getServerTime = function (_time){
         //How do i access the callback 
         //function in data.getservertime so as to return time to the 
        //school.lib.gettime?
    }

}

data.getservertime = function(callbak){

    myhub.server.getServerTime();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current design, it looks like you should pass your callback to the `getServerTime` method:

```
myhub.client.getServerTime = function (callback){
     //How do i access the callback 
     //function in data.getservertime so as to return time to the 
    //school.lib.gettime?

    // after you have retrieved the time
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
       callback(school.lib.gettime);
    }
}

...

data.getservertime = function(callback){
   myhub.server.getServerTime(callback);
}
```

Comment: how can I call the callback function from my server?